React Hook | El state que controla los errores no parece actualizarse bien
tengo este formulario en REACT-HOOK :
import { Alert, Box, Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { login, logout } from "../redux/userSlice";

const Login = () => {
  const controlStyles = {
    marginTop: 6,
  };

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const submit = (e) => {
    console.log('submit');
    e.preventDefault();
    // setUsername(e.target.username.value);
    // setPassword(e.target.password.value);
    setErrors([]);
    let newErrors = [];
    if (!username || username.trim().length === 0) {
      newErrors.push("Username can not be empty");
    }
    else if (!password ||  password.trim().length === 0) {
      newErrors.push("Password can not be empty");
    } 
    //Wrong credentials
    else if (username !== "react" || password !== "react") {
      newErrors.push("Wrong credentials ! (psst, username and password is: react)");
    }
    setErrors(newErrors);

    //Login OK
    if (errors.length === 0) {
      console.log("log in OK !");
      dispatch(login({username,password}))
    }
  };

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        submit(e);
      }}
      autoComplete="off"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "rgba(96, 178, 245, 0.31)",
        padding: "10px 60px 60px 60px",
        borderRadius: 30,
        boxShadow: "1px 1px 3px",
        marginTop: "80px",
      }}
    >
      <Box>
        <h2 align="center">Login</h2>

        <TextField
          sx={controlStyles}
          fullWidth
          size="small"
          label="Username"
          type="text"
          name="username"
          value={username}
          onChange={(e)=>{setUsername(e.target.value)}}
        />
        <TextField
          sx={controlStyles}
          fullWidth
          size="small"
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e)=>{setPassword(e.target.value)}}
        />
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Button type="submit" sx={controlStyles} variant="outlined">
          Login
        </Button>
      </Box>
      <Box marginTop={3}>
        {errors.map((error, index) => (
          <Alert key={index} severity="error">
            {error}
          </Alert>
        ))}
      </Box>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Login;

Primero, como react no tiene two-ways databinding hago que el estado se actualice en el momento que cambie el input del formulario.
Luego, en la función submit() hago una serie de validaciones, que si no se van cumpliendo se van almacenando unos errores en un array y se muestran en la vista (eso va bien).
Pero veo que falla en la comprobacion final:
 //Login OK
    if (errors.length === 0) {
      console.log("log in OK !");
      dispatch(login({username,password}))
    }

Despues de haber comprobado posibles errores me limito a verificar que no haya errores.
Y el problema con el que me estoy encontrando es que parece que no refresca bien el state.
Por ejemplo:
He parado la comprobación aqui:

Lo que esta ocurriendo es esto:

newErrors: Es la variable auxiliar que uso para ir comprobando los nuevos errores, una vez termine de añadir todos los posibles errores actualizara el stado 'errors' con su valor.
errors: Es el estado en cuestion, que renderiza las cosas en la vista. Despues de hacer setErrors deberia tener el mismo valor que newErrors

Dentro de submit, en el segundo setErrors(), ahí aun no tienes la nueva version del estado errors en scope, por lo que el if va a evaluar verdadero ya que errors.length = 0, en ese momento tu estado errors vale [], se podria resolver con un re-render, una bandera de estado y la inyección de un efecto para concluir la evaluación del if
